# Handwritten Digit Recognition on MNIST dataset using sklearn

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist, numpy-random

I want to build a Handwritten Digit Recognition on MNIST dataset using sklearn and I wanted to shuffle my train set for both features(x) and label(y). But it shows a KeyError. Let me know what is the correct way to do it.

```
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
    mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
    x,y=mnist['data'],mnist['target']
    x.shape
    y.shape
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    digit = np.array(x.iloc[45])
    digit_img = digit.reshape(28,28)
    plt.imshow(digit_img,cmap=matplotlib.cm.binary , interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")
    y.iloc[45]
    x_train, x_test = x[:60000],x[60000:]
    y_train, y_test=y[:60000],y[60000:]
    import numpy as np
    shuffled = np.random.permutation(60000)
    x_train=x_train[shuffled] -->
    y_train = y_train[shuffled] --> these two lines are throwing error
```

Comment: Can you past the full stack trace as well as the version of sklearn you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if `type(x_train)` is numpy.ndarray or DataFrame.
Since Scikit-Learn 0.24, `fetch_openml()` returns a Pandas `DataFrame` by default.
If it is dataframe, in that case you can not use `x_train[shuffled]`, which is meant for arrays.
Instead use `x_train.iloc[shuffled]`